# Why are my Postfix mails recognized as Spam?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, spam, gmail

I have a Postfix mail that I have configured pretty good. `mail-tester.com` gives me a 10/10.
I have tested on both Google and Yahoo, and checked their headers. Nothing seems to be wrong in the headers.

```
Authentication-Results: mta4213.mail.bf1.yahoo.com; 
 dkim=pass (ok) header.i=@mymail.com header.s=mail;
 spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=@mymail.com;
 dmarc=pass(p=quarantine sp=NULL dis=none) header.from=mymail.com;
```

I am not blacklisted anywhere and this mail address was never used for spam. I have checked lots of resources before coming here, but couldn't find any solutions. I don't think this is a duplicate question (I mean this is a common issue, but none of the answers worked out for me).

Comment: No, I have checked that answer before posting here.

Answer (score 1):

Passing DKIM, SPF and DMARC checks doesn't guarantee your mail won't be categorized as spam. The main purpose of these authentication methods is not to gain better reputation, but to prevent unauthorized use of your domain name. Having them in place might give some positive score in some spam filters, but wouldn't be enough, as the spammers are able to use the same methods, and they do.

Not having a bad reputation and configuring the server properly is a good start, but it doesn't automatically give good reputation.  Sending email that doesn't have any elements of typical junk mail helps passing content based filters, but some spam filters sees e.g. new domains as a possible threat. Such reputation is earned over time.

One way to investigate this further is to get spam report related headers from the receiver. The spam filters typically (but not always) adds some headers for examining their decisions, e.g.

- SpamAssassin adds [`X-Spam-Status`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPAMASSASSIN/X+Spam+Status) summary & `X-Spam-Report` for detailed scoring.
- Microsoft [Office 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/anti-spam-message-headers) adds `X-Forefront-Antispam-Report`.